# Shouldn't Area 51 have discussion features?

Tags: feature-request, area-51

Area 51 has the same look & feel as the other SO sites which makes sense since it will be intuitive to its users. I guess that it also has to do with the fact that they use the same underlying platform. But I feel that the definition phase would benefit from some sort of discussion board. What happens now when people want to discuss the scope of a new site is that the comment area at the top turns into a discussion board (but without the features that you would expect from a discussion board). You also get discussions of the scope spread out as comments to specific questions, making it hard to follow.

I realize that it's very important that Stack Overflow and the other Q&A sites don't get confused with discussion boards, but Area 51 is not a Q&A site.

Comment: I'll also mention this internally, so that people know this is an "in demand" feature; but "we're working on it folks; more info real soon".

Comment: @Marc Real soon = 6 - 8 hours/days/weeks?

Comment: @Marc I am not sure this is a dupe of that

Comment: @Jeff - my bad.

Comment: @Justin - yes, one of those 3. Or somewhere in between.

Comment: @Marc, Thanks for being clear/transparent/helpful.  One of those three. (Or none of those three) `:P`

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree.

By the way, while we impatiently wait for that "in demand" feature, the only tool to do discussion are comments. It could be an acceptable way, however the problem with comments is that they become quickly old and off-topic, because proposal are "moving targets" and may change name, subtitle, and so on, so existing comment are no longer relevant.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it is more understandable.